# Output struct data from allocated memory

Tags: c, linux, struct, malloc, realloc

I have a question, I have created a struct:

```
struct ipOut {
    unsigned int ipVer;
    unsigned int headerDWORDS;
    unsigned int headerBytes;
    unsigned int typeOfService;
    unsigned int ipLength;
    unsigned int ident;
    unsigned int ttl;
    unsigned int protocolNum;
    unsigned int checkSum;
    unsigned int protocol;
};
```

I allocated memory for it:

```
struct ipOut *ipHeadr = NULL;
ipHeadr = malloc(sizeof(*ipHeadr));//this one is inside main
```

Then, each time I'm getting data I reallocating memory and entering data to the strcut:

```
packetNum++;
ipHeadr = realloc(ipHeadr, sizeof(*ipHeadr)*packetNum);
ipHeadr->ipVer = iph->version;
ipHeadr->headerDWORDS = (unsigned int)iph->ihl;
ipHeadr->headerBytes = (unsigned int)iph->ihl*4;
ipHeadr->typeOfService = (unsigned int)iph->tos;
ipHeadr->ipLength = ntohs(iph->tot_len);
ipHeadr->ident =  ntohs(iph->id);
ipHeadr->ttl = (unsigned int)iph->ttl;
ipHeadr->protocolNum = (unsigned int)iph->protocol;
ipHeadr->checkSum = ntohs(iph->check);
ipHeadr->protocol =iph -> protocol;
```

So I tried to get this data chunk by chunk (where chunk the size of strcut), or any other way (also the way most tutorials using for malloc, like creating an array from pointer), but every time I'm trying to print it, I'm getting the same chunk many times, without changes. I cant put the code of my output, because I tried lot of different ways and don't know what to show. Also the quiestion is - how can I print the data in this way, chunk by chunk.

Comment: ipHeadr = malloc(sizeof(ipHeadr)); -> no * in the malloc

Comment: You are only `malloc`ing the size of one pointer. You need to `malloc` the size of the entire struct

Comment: Thank you, I'll remove *. How can I malloc the entire struct?(sorry if the question is dumb)

Comment: So I don't need to correct my malloc, right?

Comment: Ok, I'll try, thank you, but can you help me to get the output? And also wich type of temp pointer can I use? Should I create it with the same struct or can use like "int *temp"?

Comment: Oh, sorry for this, my bad, they are not related, these are the same kind of structs, I have put the wrong part of code, I have corrected the code.

Comment: I have tried to get it like this: "for (int ip = 0; ip < packetNum; ip++) {
        printf("%u\n", ipHeadr[ip].ipVer);
        printf("%u\n", ipHeadr[ip].headerDWORDS);", but it gives me wrong or corrupted data, the normal data I get only if I'm writing: printf("%u\n", ipHeadr->ipVer);

Comment: Oh, thank you, I'm idiot, I should enter data by this way too.